# Plotting negative-to-positive range after plotting large curve in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using Python 2 open a console and type:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.plot([2457100+i for i in range(1,100,10)],[i for i in range(1,100,10)])
plt.cla()
plt.plot([-40,-20,-0,20,40],[10,2,5,4,5])
```

The first plot will add a +2.4571e6 to the axis to make notation easier. Oddly enough, once clearing and plotting the second curve, the axis will remain with this shifting, such that the data is properly labeled but at incredibly negative numbers (-2457140...)!

This isn't reproducible if the second plot has a positive range. My current workaround is to `cla()` and re-plot the sample plot again, as after another `cla()` the axis becomes normal. This may become too costly for me (time wise), so I'm looking for other workarounds, and to make sure it is a bug. `clf()` isn't an option unfortunately, I need to retain the axes.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for quick reply, this may indeed be a version issue, Debian stable is only up to 1.4. Forgot Debian is usually behind a lot - if you want post a reply and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code in IPython 5 with matplotlib 2.0 I cannot reproduce the issue. The second plot has the correct scale after a single call to `plt.cla()`.

[image]

Comment: For future reference this is probably a bug before version 2.0.

Comment: Verified on Windows mint matplotlib 2.0 with python 2 that it works.